# Google App Engine: Give arguments to a script from URL handler?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Here is a portion of my `app.yaml` file:

```
handlers:
- url: /remote_api
  script: $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/handler.py
  login: admin
- url: /detail/(\d)+
  script: Detail.py
- url: /.*
  script: Index.py
```

I want that capture group (the one signified by `(\d)`) to be available to the script `Detail.py`. How can I do this?

Do I need to figure out a way to access GET data from `Detail.py`?

Also, when I navigate to a URL like `/fff`, which should match the `Index.py` handler, I just get a blank response.

Comment: what groups of number are you referring to?? please reframe your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I see two questions, how to pass elements of the url path as variables in the handler, and how to get the catch-all to render properly.

Both of these have more to do with the main() method in the handler than the app.yaml

1) to pass the id in the `/detail/(\d)` url, you want something like this:

```
class DetailHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, detail_id):
      # put your code here, detail_id contains the passed variable

def main():
  # Note the wildcard placeholder in the url matcher
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/details/(.*)', DetailHandler)]
  wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application)
```

2) to ensure your `Index.py` catches everything, you want something like this:

```
class IndexHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
      # put your handler code here

def main():
  # Note the wildcard without parens
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/.*', IndexHandler)]
  wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: So... you're suggesting that it's better to handle everything from one `.py` file, and parsing URL should be done there and passed to the appropriate functions, but instead of having a separate `.py` file for each different URL path?

Comment: You can have multiple handlers if you want, but most apps use a single handler for the bulk of the site. The handler scripts can import other modules to handle individual pages, if they wish.

Comment: You can have multiple `.py` files or a single. Doesn't really matter.  You still have to have the url matchers in the handler (and app.yaml).

Comment: Missing quotes in both of your code samples are messing up code coloring. Tried to edit myself, but I have a six-character minimum for edits. =/